# android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <service>

Tags: android, react-native

I am getting this error when I am upgrading my react-native version from `0.66.2` to `0.68.2`.

**Error**

> Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for . Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version of Android, we need to explicitly define the value for `android:exported` for all the **service** and **activity** in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

For example:

```
 <service android:exported="false" android:name="serviceName" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you setting android:exported but it doesn't work, when you open `AndroidManifest.xml` in *Android Studio*, you will see a tab called *Merged Manifest*. If you click the tab, the error contents are displayed.

[image]

error message for example

```xml
Merging Errors: Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
```

In my case, it was difficult because this error was displayed, but when I additionally inserted the code below in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, the error disappeared.

```xml
...
      <receiver android:name="androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
      </receiver>
...
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media/session/MediaButtonReceiver

Hope this helps you!